# How to post the updates in my site in twitter

Tags: twitter

I had a look into the following posts on stack overflow

1. Posting on twitter/facebook from my site using jQuery
2. jQuery plugin to post updates on Twitter?
3. Using only JQuery to update Twitter (OAuth)

but with no success...

The question is i am having a website that gives cricket score updates ball by ball,schedule, news etc..

And i want to post the updates in my website(scores,schedule,news) in twitter  i am using codeigniter framework in my site development and the data need to be posted in twitter will fetched from mysql database..

any help on this would do a great help for me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

So you want to connect your CodeIgniter app to Twitter?

You need to write code that accesses the [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/), or use an existing library that does that for you like: http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/

It may also be useful to read this:

http://www.mattwillo.co.uk/blog/2010-08-25/implementing-oauth-twitter-with-code-igniter/

which deals with Oauth now that [Twitter have disabled basic authentication](http://blog.twitter.com/2010/08/twitter-applications-and-oauth.html).